# Customized textview color inside tabwidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I want to create a customized `TabWidget` in android , I have done changes on the background and the selected background color for the tabs, but I want to change the color of `textview` inside each tab at selecting the `tab` . how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a selector and assign it value to the TextView like this

```
<TextView 
..
...
..
android:textColor="@color/bright_text_dark_focused"/>
```